# How do I exit from the Terminal in Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

I have installed [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)) on my Windows operating system and am able to see Terminal in Visual Studio Code Editor.

So I typed `help ssh` command and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, since then I am seeing the greater than (`>`) signs and not able to execute the command. How do I return back. I tried using `exit`, `exit 0`, `exit -f`, `quit`, `killall` and what not.

Comment: Did you try `CTRL+D` or `CTRL+C` ?

Comment: I was about to request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key combination for this.

The combination sends the special `EOF` ("End Of File") control character (`^D`), which basically tells the terminal that you are done inputting things. This is used to exit out of many interactive shells, like `python`'s for example.

Alternatively you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which sends the `SIGINT` signal to the process in an attempt to end it in a clean way. The `SIGINT` signal is usually catched by the process/application itself which allows it to clean up its files or do whatever it wants before exiting. This does not always work to exit out of interactive shells though, instead <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is used there to kill a currently running process within the interactive shell. (For example a loop you're running in a python interactive shell)